# Using Hotjar with Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-cx, hotjar

I'm searching for a service (Hotjar or similar) to session record a user interaction with a Google Dialogflow chatbot.

Most session recording tools won't display iframe contents - was hoping to see if anyone had used a service previously to record chat bot sessions, specifically with Dialogflow?

Currently we draw a blank with Hotjar being able to access Dialogflow. We have tried most other top session recorders and all have the same limitations of not showing iframe contents.